# Syntax Error, but valid Syntax?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I get an invalid Syntax Error on The ':' after the 'DisplayBands' Function, But I see nothing wrong with the syntax. I'm probably blind. Help is much appreciated (please excuse me stupidity, I'm very new to this. )

```
import time
import random

def DisplayBands:
    print("Guess the name of the band out of:")
    print("One Dimension")
    print("Take What?")
    print("Austin Eabier")
    print("Front Street Lads")
    now = time.time()
    return now
```

Comment: Please reread how to define functions in Python...

Comment: you need `()` so NO, its not valid Syntax

Answer (score 3):

A function definition requires the parenthesis at the end of the function name.

```
def DisplayBands():
                ^^ These are required
```

In this case, you are defining a function that takes 0 parameters

Answer (score 0):

You have to place `()` after function declaration:

```
def DisplayBands():
    print("Guess the name of the band out of:")
    print("One Dimension")
    print("Take What?")
    print("Austin Eabier")
    print("Front Street Lads")
    now = time.time()
    return now
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was being an idiot :)